Net Maui partial inputTransparent
.net 8, vs2022 17.11.0, shell navigation, iOS and Android.
I have a map on a page which hands pan, pinch, tap.
Now I would like to add a gesturerecognizer for swipe, so I can change my main page to "the next one" on a left swipe.
This can be done by making an invisible boxview on top of my map and detect swipes on that, but it then also blocks for other gestures, which I still need to go to the map.
What I would like is to set a control inputtransparent and then still handle gestures if I explicitly define handlers for them, but that seems to be out of the question.
Alternatively it would work to have handlers defined for the boxview which would then say specify the event was not handled, so it should pass to the next ui below.
Would anyone know of a solution for this?

What .NET version and platform do you use? Do you use MAUI Shell for navigation?

I use .net 8, vs2022 17.11.0, shell navigation, iOS and Android.

There is no easy way. Map also hands swipe gesture. If adding a swipegesture on a control, then it will collide with Map. Why not using a Button to control navigation?
